# how can I copy mp4 file from documents to photolibrary (in iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, copy, photolibrary

I have a mp4 video in my application (at Document folder)! I want to copy or move it to Photolibrary...
how can I do that? please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use assest library, here is the code

```
 NSString *documentDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *videoFile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"video.mp4"];
 UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoFile, self, @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);


- (void)video:(NSString *) videoPath didFinishSavingWithError: (NSError *) error contextInfo: (void *) contextInfo {
     if(error)
           NSLog(@\"didFinishSavingWithError: %@\", error);
}
```

Comment: UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum does not work for me :(!
and also no error occured...

Comment: Also `UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum` funciton can be uset to check if video is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
- (void)writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:(NSURL *)videoPathURL completionBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryWriteVideoCompletionBlock)completionBlock
```

method from `ALAssetsLibrary`

Comment: how can I use ALAssetsLibrary?

Answer (score 0):

To move to the Photo Library (called the Camera Roll, in iOS):

```
NSString *fileURLString = @"file://....somepath.../somefile.mp4";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURLString];

// Check compatibility
if ([[ALAssetsLibrary new] videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum:fileURL]) {
    // Save to Photo Library / Camera Roll
    [[ALAssetsLibrary new] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:fileURL completionBlock:nil];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Incompatible type. Cannot save to Photo Library.");
}
```

To copy to any folder, though you probably don't want to do this:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFilemanager defaultManager];
NSURL *originalDirectory = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/originalDir/filename.mp4"];
NSURL *newDirectory = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/newDirectory/filename.mp4"];

[fileManager moveItemAtURL:originalDirectory toURL:newDirectory error:nil];
```

If you need to download first, then do something like this:

Use `ALAssetsLibrary` as follows:

```
  #import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
  // ...
  ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [assetsLibrary writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:yourVideoURL completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
    if (error) {
      // Do something, like show an Alert View describing the error
    }
  }];
```